# why is my arduino stuck on uploading?

Tags: uploading

my arduino for the playground adafruit express gets stuck uploading, and is saying that it is not recognizing the ports. <Arduino: 1.8.16 (Windows Store 1.8.51.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Circuit Playground"

```
Sketch uses 6360 bytes (22%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.

Global variables use 351 bytes of dynamic memory.

Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port COM13

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

PORTS {COM13, } / {COM13, } => {}

Uploading using selected port: COM13

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.51.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.51.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM13 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_570140/sorting_numbers_test.ino.hex:i 



avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch



         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.51.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"



         Using Port                    : COM13

         Using Programmer              : avr109

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600

         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4

         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us

         PAGEL                         : PD7

         BS2                           : PA0

         RESET disposition             : dedicated

         RETRY pulse                   : SCK

         serial program mode           : yes

         parallel program mode         : yes

         Timeout                       : 200

         StabDelay                     : 100

         CmdexeDelay                   : 25

         SyncLoops                     : 32

         ByteDelay                     : 0

         PollIndex                     : 3

         PollValue                     : 0x53

         Memory Detail                 :



                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled

           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack

           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------

           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00

           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00

           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00

           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00

           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00

           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00



         Programmer Type : butterfly

         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader



Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding



avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

Found programmer: Id = "F"; type = @

    Software Version = �.v; Hardware Version = �. 

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't

a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?

avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1

         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override

         this check.



avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader



avrdude done.  Thank you.



the selected serial port 

 does not exist or your board is not connected



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.>
```

Comment: Not sure how windows works, I'm not using it, but it looks like serial protocol error, board might have been unplugged (physical or software side), in both case, the board is no more on that serial port number. This can occur when too many devices are serialized, consuming too much. Try to dispatch better all your serial devices on all serial ports.  Reinitialize hardware numbering & re associate the new serial port in Arduino IDE if needed, then it will be OK.

Comment: Do you have the correct hardware selected and if like the nano you may have to select a loder.

Answer (score 2):

- > ...for the playground adafruit express gets stuck...
- `avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1`

You appear to have selected the "Classic" rather than "Express" version of the board, [which are different things](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-circuit-playground-express/classic-vs-express).

- The classic you have selected uses an AVR ATMega32u4 like you'd find in the Arduino Micro/Leonardo.
- The "Express" uses an ATSAMD21 chip like an Arduino Zero.

They don't use the same family of microcontroller, bootloader, bootloader protocol, or upload tool. The boards manager package that [supports the Class board](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Arduino_Boards/) is completely different from the [one that supports the Express board](https://github.com/adafruit/ArduinoCore-samd); they are divided support along the lines of the AVR (8-bit) vs SAMD (32-bit arm) chips.

In short, choose the "Express" version of the board after you've gone through [setup process for the Express](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-circuit-playground-express/set-up-arduino-ide).  If you have problems uploading to an Express with the Express board selected, you're likely to see errors [that mention `bossac`](https://github.com/adafruit/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/1.7.5/boards.txt#L201), but you're not going to see anything about `avrdude`.